# Change default navbar color in materialize css

Tags: materialize

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmV5U.jpg

How can I change the default navbar color in materialize show in the link Above. Please help

Comment: which version of the framework you are using ? Can you also provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

In .CSS file use:

```
nav {
    background-color:#b71c1c ;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the color by modifying the value of nav class 
for example:

```
<nav class="nav blue darken-4">
```

or you can just edit the css file :) like this

```
nav {
    background-color:#0d47a1;
}
```